# how do you access entities in waterfall functions

Tags: botframework

I am not about the correct way to access the entities in my second waterfall function.

I have this code structure:

```
dialog.on('myintent', [funcA, funcB, funcC]);

function funcA(session, args, next)
{
   :
   :
   next()

function funcB(session, args, next)
{
  :
  :
  next()
```

funcA is passed the entities and intents in the arg object by the framework.  But in funcB, args is set to an object containing only a property named resumed.  I can explicitly setthe entities on a new object and pass it like next({e : entities}).  Can the framework do it and I just don't see how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the waterfall model in the botbuilder, you are either calling the next function in the waterfall explicitly with next() or the second function is a follow-up of the first with a different set of parameters.

When you call next(), you are actually calling the follow up function yourself without any data. To hand over data just hand over your objects as you did.

Also, just consider this: next(args);

If you want to hand over new input content, consider this:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },
    function (session, results, next) {
        session.send('Hello %s!', results.response);
    },
    ...
]);
```

In this case the prompt is calling the next function with the respective parameters.